# Port error when deploying express server with OIDC to Azure App Service

Tags: express, azure-web-app-service, port, openid-connect, okta

I am attempting to deploy a server to an azure app service. The server code can be found below.

The error I am getting from the log stream is:

> 2020-11-18T23:36:06.088Z ERROR - Container [container name] didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

I have PORT set to 8080 and I know that config is picking up as I can see "Server listening on port 8080" in the logs. I have tried changing WEBSITES_PORT to 80 and 8080 as I saw that other posts, but I think my issue is different.

This site was working prior to my adding auth with OIDC libraries.

The app works locally with the server code below.

```js
const https = require('https')

const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')

const key = fs.readFileSync('./key.pem')
const cert = fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')

require('dotenv').config()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('express'))
var cors = require('cors')
const OktaJwtVerifier = require('@okta/jwt-verifier')
const session = require('express-session')
const {
  ExpressOIDC
} = require('@okta/oidc-middleware')

var getUserInfo = require('./getUserInfo')

// session support is required to use ExpressOIDC
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'this should be secure',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: true,
    },
  })
)

const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
  issuer: process.env.ISSUER || 'https://[custom auth server domain].gov/oauth2/default',
  client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI ||
    'https://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback',
  appBaseUrl: process.env.APP_BASE_URL || 'https://localhost:3000',
  scope: 'openid profile',
})

// ExpressOIDC attaches handlers for the /login and /authorization-code/callback routes
app.use(oidc.router)

app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())
app.get('/userinfo', (req, res) => {
  let domain = 'dev'

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    getUserInfo.userRequest(res, req.userContext, domain)
  }
})

app.get('/authStatus', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.send(req.userContext.userinfo)
  }
})

app.post('/forces-logout', oidc.forceLogoutAndRevoke(), (req, res) => {
  // Nothing here will execute, after the redirects the user will end up wherever the `routes.logoutCallback.path` specifies (default `/`)
})

var linkObj = {not relevant links used hrefs on html based on env}

// default URL for website
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/express/index.html'))
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
})

// FAQ Path
app.get('/help', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/express/help.html'))
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
})

app.get('/links', (req, res) => {
  res.json(linkObj)
})

app.post('/forces-logout', oidc.forceLogoutAndRevoke(), (req, res) => {
  // Nothing here will execute, after the redirects the user will end up wherever the `routes.logoutCallback.path` specifies (default `/`)
})

// default URL for website
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/express/index.html'))
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
})

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
if (process.env.PORT) {
  const server = https.createServer(app)
  server.listen(port)
} else {
  const server = https.createServer({
    key: key,
    cert: cert
  }, app)
  server.listen(port)
}

console.debug('Server listening on port ' + port)

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10)

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port
  }

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's this line that could be giving you issues:

```
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
```

I'd try changing it to:

```
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080')
```

You'll also need to change these lines to have your public URL, not `localhost`:

```
  redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI ||
    'https://localhost:3000/authorization-code/callback',
  appBaseUrl: process.env.APP_BASE_URL || 'https://localhost:3000',
```

After you change these, you'll need to update your app on Okta to your production redirect URI.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The process.env variables come into play only when deploying to Azure. The variables to right of || are for local only. I have an OIDC config set up in Okta for local, and another for the dev environment where I am having trouble deploying.